# Update ListView items data on horizontal RecyclerView item selected

Tags: java, android, listview, nullpointerexception, android-recyclerview

I want to update the list items data on selection of horizontal RecyclerView  textview position.

I am getting a Null Pointer Exception when I set adapter, the ListView is null.

My code is as below:

activity_main.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

   <RelativeLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".ChapterList"
android:id="@+id/relativeroot"
android:background="@drawable/bgimage">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/toolbarbg"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/back_white" />

    <Textview
        android:id="@+id/toolbartitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_play"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/play" />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:id="@+id/viewpager">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_chapter"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
```

MainActivity.java

```
         mListView.setAdapter(chapterListItem);
         RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);

        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

PagerAdaptre.java

```
      public class PagerAdapter extends 
       RecyclerView.Adapter<PagerAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
        Context context;
        ArrayList<Chapter> arrayList;
         Mainactivity mainactivity;

        public PagerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Chapter> arrayList) {
           this.context = context;
           this.arrayList = arrayList;
        }


public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
         public TextView textView;
          public ImageView imageView;

          public MyViewHolder(View view){
             super(view);
             textView=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_chapter_no);
             imageView=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.img_selected);
               }
           }
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        Viewitemview=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
        .inflate(R.layout.viewpager_item,parent,false);
    return new MyViewHolder(itemview);
    }

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    final Chapter chapter = arrayList.get(position);
    holder.textView.setText("" + chapter.getChapternumber());
    if (position == 0) {
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.pagination);
    }
    holder.textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.pagination);
            mainactivity=new MainActivity();
              mainactivity.setpos
             (Integer.parseInt(""+chapter.getChapternumber()));
        }

    });

}


   @Override
  public int getItemCount() {
      return arrayList.size();
 }
 }
```

MainActivity.java

```
void setpos(int position) {

    chapterpos=position;//chappos is int variable
    setlistdata(chapterpos);
}
private void setlistdata(int position){
    namelist.clear();
    chapterListItem=null;
    chapterListItem = new ChapterListItem(ChapterList.this, namelist);
    try {


        chapterListItem.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mListView.setAdapter(chapterListItem);// i am getting 
        listview null here

     } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My Logcat is below:

```
01-25 17:11:39.904 26929-26929/com.ex.Appname

W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: 
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
01-25 17:11:39.904 26929-26929/
 W/System.err:     at MainActivity.setlistdata(MainActivity.java:625)
01-25 17:11:39.904 26929-26929/

W/System.err:     at MainActivity.setpos(ChapterList.java:581)
01-25 17:11:39.904 26929-26929/

W/System.err:     at PagerAdapter$1.onClick(PagerAdapter.java:61)
01-25 17:11:39.904 26929-26929/

W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4783)
01-25 17:11:39.904 26929-26929/

W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19887)
01-25 17:11:39.904 26929-26929/

W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
01-25 17:11:39.904 26929-26929/

W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-25 17:11:39.904 26929-26929/

W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
01-25 17:11:39.904 26929-26929/

 W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5290)
01-25 17:11:39.904 26929-26929/

W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-25 17:11:39.904 26929-26929/

W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
01-25 17:11:39.904 26929-26929/

W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:911)
01-25 17:11:39.904 26929-26929/

W/System.err:     atcom.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:706)
```

Comment: paste logcat...

Comment: I had  Posted logcat

Comment: Create a [mcve]. Don't post sections your your Activity code.

Comment: Anyway, the recyclerview has android:id="@+id/viewpager" and that's just really confusing

Answer (score 0):

Have you found your listview(declared in xml) in your MainActivity ?
Include this below line -

```
mListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.your_listview_id)
```

Comment: yes when oncreate() is called the listview.setadapter works fine but again i try to set the data it gives me null pointer exception

Comment: first try to pass your mListView in constructor of recycler view adapter, then from that adapter class, pass this to setPos( (Integer.parseInt(""+chapter.getChapternumber()) ,mlistview) , then also pass this to setlistdata like this  private void setlistdata(int position,ListView mlistview){  // use this listview to set your adapter.}

Comment: In     private void setlistdata(int position, mListView or ListView listview){      listview.setadapter(chapterListItem );    }

Comment: when you defining this use setlistdata(int position,ListView listview){}   and when you are calling this use setlistdata(chapterpos,mListView); I hope this is clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void setlistdata(int position){
    namelist.clear(); // **You are clearing the nameList here, so It might possible you should add new data before use it again.**
    chapterListItem=null;
    chapterListItem = new ChapterListItem(ChapterList.this, namelist);
try {

    chapterListItem.notifyDataSetChanged();
    mListView.setAdapter(chapterListItem);// i am getting 
    listview null here

 } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

Comment: Can you elaborate more because the data of name list has changed   and i want to set that data again

Answer (score 0):

```
mainactivity=new MainActivity();
```

You just created a new Activity and lost all references to the one that you used findViewById on.

Rule of thumb: Never ever make a `new` Activity. You need to handle the item selected event differently. Ideally setting it from the Activity, not the Adapter, so that you can call the necessary methods

Something to keep in mind: how are you going to "go back" a chapter? Once you click, you reload the entire adapter, losing the old data, so I guess you've not thought about that yet

Comment: Then how i can reload the listview based on selection of recyclerview item position ?

Comment: You need to use the existing Activity. That's all I'm saying. Therefore your click event needs to exist in the Activity if you need to overwrite the list data. http://antonioleiva.com/recyclerview-listener/